# best practice for SC2155: declare and assign separately

Tags: bash

Am writing a bash script and my IDE complaining about the following declarations:

```
local grey=$(tput setaf 154)
local red=$(tput setaf 196)
local bold=$(tput bold)
local default=$(tput sgr0)
```

It says this:

```
Declare and assign separately to avoid masking return values.
See SC2155.
```

I understand what this warning means and I am able to get rid of this warning but my final code looks so ugly.

I can suppress the warnings this way:

```
# shellcheck disable=SC2155
local grey=$(tput setaf 154)

# shellcheck disable=SC2155
local red=$(tput setaf 196)

# shellcheck disable=SC2155
local bold=$(tput bold)

# shellcheck disable=SC2155
local default=$(tput sgr0)
```

Or i can separate the declaration and the value assignment this way:

```
local grey
grey=$(tput setaf 154)

local red
red=$(tput setaf 196)

local bold
bold=$(tput bold)

local default
default=$(tput sgr0)
```

The soutions above are so verbose.

I can also do this:

```
local grey; grey=$(tput setaf 154)
local red; red=$(tput setaf 196)
local bold; bold=$(tput bold)
local default; default=$(tput sgr0)
```

But I am not sure what is the best way to solve it properly.
Maybe I can ignore this warning, because my expression is fine. Not sure what is the best way to write a clean bash script that aligns with the standards.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think there's a single answer for “best practice”. The way I would write it is

```
local grey red bold default
grey=$(tput setaf 154)
red=$(tput setaf 196)
bold=$(tput bold)
default=$(tput sgr0)
```

The reason not to combine a declaration like `local` and an assignment that involves a command substitution is that the status of `var=$(somecommand)` is the exit code of `somecommand`, but the status of `local …` is always 0. Thus `local var=$(somecommand)` hides any error from `somecommand`. For the same reason, you shouldn't put multiple command substitutions in the same assignment.

This of course only matters if you actually pay attention to the command's status, either by checking `$?` or by turning on `set -e`.

You might choose to play loose with commands that are very unlikely to fail, e.g. `destination_file=$(dirname -- "$other_file")/$(basename -- "$source_file")`. `tput` is not one of those: it will fail if the script runs on a terminal that's missing the requested capability.

Another reason not to combine a declaration with an assignment is that it only works for scalars, not for arrays. Combining a declaration with a literal string or number (`local filename='hello.txt'`, `local -i n=3`) is fine.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to provide the `-r` (readonly) option to `local`:

```bash
local -r grey=$(tput setaf 154)
local -r red=$(tput setaf 196)
local -r bold=$(tput bold)
local -r default=$(tput sgr0)
```

Shellcheck won't complain about this because readonly variables have to be assigned while declared. Of course that doesn't address the underlying reason for SC2155, i.e. the return values still get swallowed, so it probably can't be called "best practice". But if you're going to ignore the return values anyway it shouldn't matter.